# How can I read only a percentage of records from a mysql table in talend

Tags: mysql, talend

I'm facing a problem with Talend. I want to read only a percentage of records from a MySQL database table and do some processing on them, but I cannot find a way to read only a portion of random records.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10` all you need to do now is work out a value for `10` that is the x% of rows you want to see

Comment: @RiggsFolly, good idea! You could get the total row count in another query and use that.

Comment: @Carassus Precisely my friend

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried to use LIMIT in the way you suggested, but LIMIT doesn't accept variables

Comment: Of course it does. Please show us the code, and then ping so we know there is something to look at

Answer (score 0):

Based on RiggsFolly comment.

You can use `"SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT "+context.NB_ROWS` with NB_ROWS being a context variable initialized with a previous query (with a count).